# How to scrape images from a website using selenium and write them to my local disk

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

My problem is that my code overwrites the previous image in the folder. I have tried changing mode from 'wb' to 'ab' to no avail. Somebody please help. I am pretty new to this. I want to write all images once I run the for loop.
Thanks.`

```
for i in range (84):
img=requests.get(res[i])

with open(f'E:\images/.jpg','ab') as f:
    f.write(img.content)
```

Comment: Please fix indentation. Current code should lead to `IndentationError`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(84):
    img = requests.get(res[i])

    with open(f'E:\images/{i}.jpg','ab') as f:
        f.write(img.content)
```